# Bulk printing PDF-Files on server side

Tags: asp.net, printing, asp.net-mvc-4, server-side, bulk

I asked the following question on the MSDN-forums. It actually got answered, but still i couldn't come up with a solution after a couple of hours of research. So maybe you guys have an idea. Here it goes...:

I have the following specification for which i should develop a prototype with ASP.Net MVC 4:

In a SQL-DB there are up to 1000 PDF-files stored.

The User of an ASP.Net MVC 4 wep application should be able to start a server side bulk print job. Also he should choose wich network printer the job is sent to.

Is this at all possible in ASP.Net MVC 4? And if so, how would one approach this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help, tips or steps in the right direction.

Comment: Which part of the problem are you having?
1. Get a list of network/server-local printers?
2. Print PDF to the printer.

Comment: Hi Joseph, the problem is as follows: the network printers are installed on the client via the corresponding ip-address. The user would select a couple of pdf-files (which would be flagged in the database for print), then select a printer and start the print job on the server side.Then a printer job on a application server would wait for a command from the asp.net mvc web application which will tell it to look for flagged files in the db and then print them on the chosen printer. Hope this makes the whole problem a bit clearer.

Comment: Hi, look at the 2nd link in the answer below. Basically, you add the client machine into your Server as a local printer (it is still a network printer). That way, your server will have access to it.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't actually answer your question: Problem 1:  Get a list of network/server-local printers in the asp.net mvc app; Problem 2: giving this info the server side print.er job

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this:

Get Network Printers: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=148

-and this-

Print to a printer: [Printing from ASP.NET to a network printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729153/printing-from-asp-net-to-a-network-printer)

Comment: Looks like the printing portion requires the network printer to be installed locally via IP address to a port on the box. That heavily restricts the choice of printers that can be used if every printer in the building needs to be installed on the server first.

Comment: Great, the above mentioned links were quite helpful. Last but not least there is the question of the actual printer job. There it just would be helpful if you guys could nod me in the right direction. Would one implement the jobs logic on the server side code of the ASP.NET application itself or would one develop a complete separate service (e.g. a command-line-app) which runs on the server?

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229823/programmatically-hello-world-default-server-side-printer-in-asp-net-mvc